# Questions regarding Extending JFrame in a class?

Tags: java, jframe

Okay, I'm NOT a Java noob, it just so happens that I've forgotten a tad bit about core Java while I was learning more fun stuff like MySQL, Servlets, Java EE, JDBC etc etc; so don't frame your answers as if I were a beginner. Now the question.....

I'm writing a class (lets say `ThisIsAJFrameExtendingClass`) which extends JFrame, and to minimize confusion with my overall project, I also want to park some other utility methods in `ThisIsAJFrameExtendingClass`. I intend this class (`ThisIsAJFrameExtendingClass`) to seek certain inputs from the user following which; commit suicide (ie  `dispose()`). So, my question is, how can I independently use the utility methods inside the class without any JFrame popping up on the user screen.

I'ld like a solution with the help of multiple constructors inside the `ThisIsAJFrameExtendingClass` class, where, invoking the argument-less constructor return JFrame and the second constructor with a boolean argument gives access to the utility methods.

**[UPDATE]**

Ohh.... I just had a thought, the utility method has a return type of ArrayList so, assuming the utility method is called `utilMethod()` then:

`ArrayList<String> pring = new ThisIsAJFrameExtendingClass().utilMethod();`

will the above code output any JFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the utility methods `static`, in which case they can be invoked using `ThisIsAJFrameExtendingClass.<method name>` without creating an instance.

The stuff about constructors doesn't really make sense to me. A class's constructor always returns an instance of that class. It can't return "something else" because of a parameter you pass in.

**[Edited to respond to the question's Update]:**

`new ThisIsAJFrameExtendingClass()` will create an instance of your class, running its constructor (and the default constructor of all superclasses). This may allocate other resources (such as other Swing components or whatever) that each constructor in the inheritance tree requires. So a `JFrame` is created, but if you only call `utilMethod()` and never hang on to the reference to the frame, it will be garbage collected and its resources freed at some point in the future.

Creating a JFrame instance to call a single utility method on it isn't a particularly efficient way to go about things, but it won't cause any problems. (As [Chad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48839/chad-okere) says, by default a `JFrame` isn't visible, so users won't see anything if you're using it in "util" mode).

As to returning an `ArrayList`, as a general rule when using collections, you should return the highest level interface that makes sense rather than a concrete class. So in this case, consider returning `List<String>` or even `Collection<String>`.

Comment: yep, my bad, like I mentioned in the question, I kinda forgot quite a bit about `inheritance` in core Java, since I was busy with other things

Answer (score 1):

I have a lot of trouble getting behind your concept, which sounds a bit confused to me. At the very least, it sounds like horrible design. But I do have some suggestions:

1. You can make those utility methods static, then you won't need to instantiate your class at all to use them. This would be the simplest case.
2. You could pack your utility methods inside a static inner class of your frame, which essentially gets you around the requirement to only have one class per file.

<s>Finally, do you just want the JFrame to disappear once the user is done with it, or do you want to terminate the application? `dispose()` will do only the former, your app will continue to run as a kind of headless zombie process.</s>

Comment: Like I earlier mentioned in the question, I have forgotten quite a bit about core Java, hence, the faulty concept

Comment: The dispose() method, will exit the JVM if the frame being disposed is the only frame running on the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's assume the methods you need aren't static.

In that case, remember the JFrame won't show up unless you call setVisible(true); So just make sure you never **show** the frame, and you can use whatever functions you want without it annoying the user.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could design it properly and break out the utility methods into a separate class...

Comment: No, I already have a confused project organization, not keen on increasing project complexity even more